# Finding the Maximum and Minimum Number of Operations to Delete all Element in a Circular List

Tags: java, list, algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

In a circular list of length n, where a1 is adjacent to a2, a2 is adjacent to a3, and an is adjacent to a1. Each operation can delete one number, after each deletion, if there exists adjacent equal numbers, one of them will be automaticlly deleted until there are no adjacent equal numbers in the list.

For example, consider a circular list [1, 2, 3, 2]. If we delete the number 3, one of the adjacent 2's will be automatically deleted, resulting in [1, 2]. If we then delete the number 2, the list becomes [1]. Finally 1 is deleted, and the operation number is 3, because automatically deletions are not included.

I would like to know the maximum and minimum number of operations required to delete all the elements in the circular list. What are the approaches or algorithms that can be used to solve this problem efficiently? Java code is better.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, and now I have modified this question.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. That does clear things up. But, now, can you tell us about what you tried, and your thoughts about why it might not have worked? Please include Java code of your attempt, if you are able.

Comment: That information should be in the question body. The admins here don't want comments to be used for chat.

Comment: Ok, I put my information to the body

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to use a map to record the occurrence count of each number. If there is a number that appears only once or there are at least three different numbers in total, I will return the length of the array. Otherwise, if the scenario is similar to "1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2", I will return the length of the array divided by 2 plus 1 (each deletion triggers an automatic removal, reducing the length by 2; when the length reaches 2, two deletions can be performed). But I wonder if it is right and how to prove it.